# Getting error : Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 47

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-deployment, contract-debugging

While developing a Smart Contract with Solidity on Remix, after creating the contract I'm trying to calling function setGrantAddress:

`mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;`
but when I call `setGrantAddress` for address `["0x14723a09acff6d2a60dcdf7aa4aff308fddc160c,"0x4b0897b0513fdc7c541b6d9d7e929c4e5364d2db"]`

error as ---> *transact to PublicAddress.setGrantAddress errored: Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 47.*

Any idea how can I properly call setGrantAddress?
[image]

program code link:-[Unable to input address[] parameter in remix](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/66093/unable-input-data-in-address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your parameters, you are missing `"` at the end of first address, hence the error.